# any id in listview in listfragment not working

Tags: android

i have created a program for list fragment where my layout contains a fragment and the fragment contains a inflated listview
the problem is if a give the listview any other id except android:list it is not working .
why it is so
what android:list refers to.
the code is 
Main layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/lfrag1"
        android:name="com.example.chap5.lfrag"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Layout which is inflated for each fragment

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The id of the listview that is given here as android:list ,it is working for it .but for any other id it is not working
kindly update
thanks 
tejinder

Comment: shows us your fragment code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a requirement of using `ListFragment`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html

> ListFragment has a default layout that consists of a single list view. However, if you desire, you can customize the fragment layout by returning your own view hierarchy from `onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)`. To do this, your view hierarchy *must* contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or `list` if it's in code)

If you want to use another id, don't extend `ListFragment`, just extend `Fragment` and do it yourself.

Comment: but cant we restrict that listfragment can only include listview and not bind the id that it cannot have a id different from android:list

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean. If you don't want to customise it, don't extend onCreateView. If you do want to, your list has to have the id "@android:id/ist". If you want something other than that, just use a Fragment, then you can totally customise it. Everything you can do in ListFragment you can do in Fragment. It's just like a template.

Comment: i just wanted to inquire why it is necessary to bind this id to the listview .why cant we have any other id .is this id used by the android runtime to use the listview attached by default or by our createview